# How to create HTTP POST Request Body content with WCF REST (Starter Kit)

Tags: xml, wcf, api, rest

I'm integrating an app with [ZenDesk](http://www.zendesk.com/). They have a [REST API](http://www.zendesk.com/api/rest_introduction). I need to send POX in the request body. I'm using the WCF REST Starter Kit.

**How do I programmatically add my xml to the request body?**

Here's my unit test:

```
        [Test]
        public void Can_create_user()
        {
            // Arrange
            http = new HttpClient("http://myapp.zendesk.com/");
            http.TransportSettings.Credentials = new NetworkCredential
                                               ("joe@admin.com", "passW0rd");
            http.DefaultHeaders.Accept.Add("application/xml");
            var form = new HttpUrlEncodedForm();
            var expectedStatusCode = 201;

            var request = new XDocument(
                new XElement("user",
                             new XElement("email", "joe@user.com"),
                             new XElement("name", "Joe User"),
                             new XElement("roles", "4"),
                             new XElement("restriction-id", "4")));

            form.Add("body", request.ToString());

            // Act
            var response = http.Post("users.xml", form.CreateHttpContent());
            var content = response.Content.ReadAsString();

            // Assert
            response.EnsureStatusIs(expectedStatusCode);
```

Comment: I recently wrote a blog post on some of the other things you can do with HttpContent.  http://www.bizcoder.com/index.php/2009/12/09/http-content-instead-of-streams/

Comment: Cheers Darrel. Very useful blog post. I've Evernoted it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the static method Microsoft.Http.HttpContent.Create()

```
var response = http.Post("users.xml", HttpContent.Create(requestXML.ToString()));
```

Comment: And also, replace this 

http.DefaultHeaders.Accept.Add("application/xml");

with this

http.DefaultHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8");